# Using index values as prefix in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Prefix searching in elastic seems pretty straightforward (playing with the analyzer aside). From the docs, if I wanted to find `quick brown fox` in my index I'd do something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "quick brown f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Great! But, what if the value in my index was `quick brown f` and I was searching with

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "message": {
        "query": "quick brown fox"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I still want to use the benefits of a prefix index for speed but the index entry is a prefix of the search, rather than the other way around.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a partial ID match, the order of the numbers in my ID is important and what I want to do is quickly identify any ID value that is a partial match. That is:

Searching for `12345678` should match index entry `1234567890` (which is a simple prefix search) but should also match `12345` in the index (which is the use-case I have defined above). There will be millions of items in this index and speed is important here so I was curious if there's a way to set this up using either prefix settings or something else. I was hoping to avoid the overhead of regex or similar but if that's the way then fair enough.

Comment: Does searching for `12345678` needs to match `1`, `12`, `123`, `1234`, `12345`, ...? Basically all prefixes of that id as well as all tokens that the id is a prefix of?

Comment: You can do prefix search with first character - doesn't suit?

Comment: @val yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Gibbs Not sure I entirely get you. So search for everything starting with `1` then apply a filter/search to the results? Basically use the prefix as a pre-filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve what you need using an [`edge_ngram` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html). The idea is to create an analyzer that would index all prefixes of the ID, and also use the same analyzer at search time in order to analyze the search input the same way as the indexed data.

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "prefix_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "prefixes"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "prefixes": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "prefix_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "prefix_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can index a sample document:

```
POST test/_doc/
{
  "id": "123456789"
}
```

In the above document, the following `id` values have been indexed: `1`, `12`, `123`, `1234`, `12345`, `123456`, `1234567`, `12345678`, `123456789`.

Now, if you search for `12345`, you're going to find `123456789` (the search input is a prefix of the indexed ID)

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "id": "12345"
    }
  }
}
```

But if you search for `1234567890`, you're also going to find `123456789` (the indexed ID is a prefix of the search input)

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "id": "1234567890"
    }
  }
}
```

Quick note regarding n-grams: You can modify `min_gram` and `max_gram` to more closely fit your needs. Also note that depending on the volume of your data, your index can grow pretty big if you index a lot of prefixes.

Comment: Good one @Val. plus1. I have a doubt w.r.t `n-gram` - how do we control the index size?

Comment: ok. In this particular use case, it is not possible. Am I correct? Either we need to sacrifice memory cost to meet the req or the requirement has to be changed.

Comment: @Gibbs Right now there's nothing hinting at the fact that there is a performance issue. If that's the case, we can find ways to alleviate the problem, but as you know [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: That's pretty cool! Thanks @val. Let me get it running then I'll accept the answer. I reckon a big index is fine for now. Our problem was never going to be a small data one!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I may go a different way. Our IDs can be expressed numerically so in this case if I had an index value of:

`12345`

with the max length of an ID value being ten then in actuality I could pad the ID with 0s to get the same order of magnitude for anything, regardless of populated digits. For example, the above would become:

`1234500000`

while `12345678` would become `1234567800`.

For the first example, anything that shared the prefix would be between `1234500000` and `1234599999`.

I can therefore search my index for either case by checking if the range of the minimum and maximum ID values overlap.

So my search would simply be:

```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "range": {
                        "min_poss_value": {
                            "gte": min_value_to_search,
                            "lte": max_value_to_search
                        }
                    }}, {
                    "range": {
                        "max_poss_value": {
                            "gte": min_value_to_search,
                            "lte": max_value_to_search
                        }
                    }
                }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1
            }
        }
    }
```

...and no, I didn't design the ID system, I only work here.

Comment: Indeed, if the IDs are numeric, your approach makes sense. Mine stays if the IDs are alphanumeric ;-)

Comment: Agreed. Indeed, there is still a bit of debate on that topic in-house. Thanks for you input though, really clever solution.

I'm gonna accept yours as I think it answers my requirements, I just described them poorly.